# check file type upload in php strange behaviour

Tags: php

how is this work

```
if($_FILES['SelectedFile']['type'] != 'image/png' or 'image/jpg' or 'image/gif' || 'image/jpeg'){
    outputJSON('Unsupported filetype uploaded.');
}
```

my file is something.PNG and it doesn't pass above if statement. I change the code to `'image/PNG'` because it might be the uppercase issue but it was not the case. I wonder why.

**edit**

```
var_dump($_FILES['SelectedFile']['type'])

array(5) { ["name"]=> string(11) "Capture.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE58A.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(7818) }
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_FILES['SelectedFile'])` show?

Comment: @JohnConde[array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "Capture.png"
  ["type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE58A.tmp"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(7818)
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$haystack = array("image/png","image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/gif");
if(!in_array(strtolower($_FILES['SelectedFile']['type']), $haystack){
    outputJSON('Unsupported filetype uploaded.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is incorrect, it should be:

```
$type = $_FILES['SelectedFile']['type'];
if ($type != 'image/png' && $type != 'image/jpg' && $type != 'image/gif' && $type != 'image/jpeg') {
    outputJSON('Unsupported filetype/uploaded');
}
```

*Or* doesn't distribute in programming languages like it does in natural languages.